# How to use a variable as the field key for a query in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

how to use the  `title` variable from the `req.params`, as the field key for a query in mongodb?

i would like to use `const { title } = req.params` in the query field like this`{title:1}`

i tried this below but it is not working

```
router.get('/books/:title', async (req, res) => {

  const { title } = req.params

  const book = await books.find({ title:1, _id:0 });

  res.send(book);

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--you're not using the query param at all right now; why can't you actually use it?

Comment: @Dave Newton i think he is trying to use that in `projection`, so he wants that as dynamic. @Manny whether I'm correct??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `[]` for dynamic variable as follows:

1. If you want to use it query you can use it straight forward as follows

   `router.get('/books/:title', async (req, res) => {

     const { title } = req.params

     const book = await books.find({ [title]:"Some Title"});

     res.send(book);

   });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
const book = await books.find({},{title:1});
```